# set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14) does not automatically link against stdc++ in linux

Tags: c++, cmake, libstdc++

I successfully build and execute a tgbot example for both Windows (Visual Studio 2022) and Linux (gcc 11) using the following `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system REQUIRED)
find_package(CURL)
include_directories(/usr/local/include ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
if (CURL_FOUND)
    include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_definitions(-DHAVE_CURL)
endif()

add_executable(tgbotExample1 echobot.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tgbotExample1 PRIVATE TgBot)
if (LINUX)
    target_link_libraries(tgbotExample1 PRIVATE stdc++ ${_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR}/${VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET}/lib/libTgBot.a ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
endif ()
```

The [`CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp/blob/master/samples/echobot/CMakeLists.txt) provided by the repo does not link against `stdc++` but for my case if I don't include it `target_link_libraries(tgbotExample1 PRIVATE stdc++ ...`, I get many link errors.

```
# Original
target_link_libraries(echobot /usr/local/lib/libTgBot.a ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${CURL_LIBRARIES})

# versus Mine
target_link_libraries(tgbotExample1 PRIVATE stdc++ ${_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR}/${VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET}/lib/libTgBot.a ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
```

My question is:

1. isn't the job of `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)` to use `stdc++` for linking? Why do I have to include it but the original `CMakeLists.txt` does not have it?
2. How the original [`CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp/blob/master/samples/echobot/CMakeLists.txt) will link against `stdc++` without explicitly mentioning it?

Comment: Regarding the formal question: No. `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)` tells CMake to generate scripts that will invoke the compiler to compile to the C++14 Standard Revision. This isn't very helpful to you with respect to fixing [whatever problem lead you to asking this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so you may want to reword the question.

Comment: Ah. Good update. The default behaviour of most C++ toolchains is to link in whatever Standard Library implementation came with the toolchain. You typically only need to specify the Standard Library implementation if you are not going to use the default.

Comment: On the revised question 1, the writer of the project may have been using, and assuming that you are using as well, a C++ toolchain where C++14 or better is the default Standard Revision. If you are building on a Mac where the default is to build for C++98 or using an older compiler, you'll have to force a minimum Standard Revision.